# Сохранять маркеры с их значениями

Tags: java, android, google-maps

На данный момент добавляю свои маркеры в карту следующим образом:

```
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
    Marker marker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(new LatLng(47.045029, 28.861427))
            .title("Marker"));
    Marker marker2 = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(new LatLng(47.000327, 28.867950))
            .title("Marker"));
    Marker marker3 = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(new LatLng(47.024204, 28.889236))
            .title("Marker"));

    builder.include(marker.getPosition());
    builder.include(marker2.getPosition());
    builder.include(marker3.getPosition());
}
```

Но так как кол-во этих маркеров будет со временем увеличиваться, то подумываю как можно  иначе хранить эти маркеры(как вариант расматриваю: при помощи SQLite).

Подскажите пожалуйста как возможно оптимизировать работу приложения, а именно связать работу с **SQLite**.

Comment: Вы правильно думаете, что хранить записи с координатами можно в бд. Взятие из базы происходит быстро

Comment: У вас будет таблица с категориями и таблица с маркерами, соответственно в таблице с маркерами будет столбец ссылающиеся на по id на категорию

Comment: `как можно иначе хранить эти маркеры` – а как Вы их храните сейчас? Вариант с базой данных вполне подходит.